# Different path URL for FileManager everytime I open the app

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I want to create one folder in the fileManager root path, but before creating it, I want to check that the folder exist or not, and if not, I will create, otherwise will leave it

here are the function that I use

```
public func isDirectoryExist(path: String) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var isDir : ObjCBool = false
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory:&isDir) {
        if isDir.boolValue {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
}


public func createNewDirectory(name: String) {
    
    let DocumentDirectory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
    let DirPath = DocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
    do
    {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: DirPath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        Logger.logError("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
    Logger.logInfo("Dir Path = \(DirPath!)")
}
```

Now, when I check the folder existing, it's always false and create a new folder and it happen every time

```
    func createARObjectDirectory() {
        let rootURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        if isDirectoryExist(path: "\(rootURL.absoluteString)\(DefaultURL.arObjectUrlDirectoryName)") {
            Logger.logServer("ARObject directly found")
        } else {
            createNewDirectory(name: DefaultURL.arObjectUrlDirectoryName)
        }
    }
```

Then I print the root url, and seems the hash in the middle of url is always different, how I can check it?

```
 file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5AD0690B-498D-4309-8BD0-191FB88766AC/Documents/AR-Object/
 file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/41D35A54-1807-417E-AE29-311D43FCC21D/Documents/AR-Object/
 file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7E385CC-7921-4C37-B9BF-BCEFFC2AEE9E/Documents/AR-Object/
 file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4748B014-5E55-46BB-BC83-394A6BC27292/Documents/AR-Object/
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong API. `absoluteString` (in `rootURL.absoluteString`) returns the string representation including the scheme `file://`. The correct API for file system URLs is `path`

I recommend to use the URL related API as much as possible

```
public func directoryExists(at url: URL) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var isDir : ObjCBool = false
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory:&isDir) {
        return isDir.boolValue
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

and compose the URL in a more reliable way

```
func createARObjectDirectory() {
    let documentsDirectory = URL.documentsDirectory
    if directoryExists(at: documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(DefaultURL.arObjectUrlDirectoryName)  {
        Logger.logServer("ARObject directly found")
    } else {
        createNewDirectory(name: DefaultURL.arObjectUrlDirectoryName)
    }
}
```

And this is *swiftier* too

```
public func createNewDirectory(name: String) {
    
    let documentsDirectory = URL.documentsDirectory
    let dirURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
    do
    {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: dirURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        Logger.logError("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
    Logger.logInfo("Dir Path = \(dirPath.path)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual path to your app's documents directory is subject to change. You should use relative paths from the documents directory, and not try to compare paths between runs.

(I believe the path changes each time you rebuild your app or reinstall it, but is {fairly} stable for app store builds.)

Are you saying that the directory you create inside the documents directory goes away between runs? That should not be true. The contents of the documents directory should persist.